# TensorFlow: how can I sum a list of tf.Variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've got a 3D array that is of `tf.Variable` type. `tf.reduce_sum` only works on individual tensors. I've tried doing:

```
tf.reduce_sum([tf.reduce_sum(mat) for mat in var_3Dlist])
```

...but `tf.reduce_sum()` expects a tensor and not a list. Can I convert it to a tensor somehow, or is there another, better way to do it? I haven't found anything in the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`tf.reduce_sum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_sum) op works on 3-D tensors and variables (and in general any rank or tensor or variable). However, if you have a **list** of 2-D tensors (or variables), you should use the [`tf.add_n()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#add_n) op to add together the values in the list:

```
var_3Dlist = ...  # List of 3-D variables.
sum_list = [tf.reduce_sum(mat) for mat in var_3Dlist]
sum = tf.add_n(sum_list)
```

Comment: Today tf.reduce_sum seemed to work on the list returned by tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES). But tf.losses.get_regularization_loss() uses tf.add_n on the same list. The difference now is in reduction of dimensions. Reduce sum by default reduces all dimensions, whereas add_n adds element-wise, preserving all inner dimensions.